# How do I get more/any of this to render in the designer?

Tags: wpf, xaml

None of this xaml shows up in the designer, I'm not very familiar with wpf in general, but I'm sure at least some of it could be worked to show up in the designer.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Company.EDIS.Electronic.Physician.DifferentialDiagnosisTab"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:COmpany.EDIS.Electronic.Physician"
    xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:Company.UI.Controls;assembly=Company.UI"
    xmlns:extensions="clr-namespace:Company.UI.Controls.Extensions;assembly=Company.UI"
    xmlns:dataModels="clr-namespace:Company.Foundation.DataModels;assembly=Company.Foundation"
    xmlns:lang="clr-namespace:Company.UI.Localization.TranslationByMarkupExtension;assembly=Company.UI.Localization"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ecompanyion/blend/2008" 
    Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundLightBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="600"
    x:Name="ThisWindow">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
            <Setter Property = "HorizontalOffset" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property = "VerticalOffset" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property = "Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
            <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property = "FontSize" Value="14"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6"  />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="QuestionSectionStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource QuestionSectionBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource QuestionSectionBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0,3,10" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
        </Style>

        <!--DeleteButtonCard-->
        <Style x:Key="DeleteButtonCard" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6"  />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
                            <Border Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                               VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                               FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                               Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                               Cursor="Hand"/>
                                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                           x:Name="IMAGE" Visibility="Hidden" Opacity=".2" Height="75" Width="100" 
                                           Source="pack://application:,,,/Company.UI.Images;component/CommonImages/Delete.png" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="IMAGE" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!--AddButtonCard-->
        <Style x:Key="AddButtonCard" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"  />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness=".5" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                               VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                               FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                               Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                               Cursor="Hand" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                           x:Name="IMAGE" Visibility="Hidden" Height="25" Width="25" 
                                           Source="pack://application:,,,/Company.UI.Images;component/CommonImages/Add.png" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="IMAGE" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!--AvailableDiagnosisDataModel-->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dataModels:DiagnosisDataModel}" x:Key="AvailableDiagnosisDataModel">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource AddButtonCard}" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Content="{Binding ShortDescription}" ToolTip="{Binding LongDescription}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                    Command="{Binding Content.DiagnosisClickedCommand, ElementName=ThisWindow}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!--SelectedDiagnosisDataModel-->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dataModels:DiagnosisDataModel}" x:Key="SelectedDiagnosisDataModel">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonCard}" Height="150" Width="180" 
                    Command="{Binding Content.SelectedDiagnosisClickedCommand, ElementName=ThisWindow}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}" ToolTip="{Binding LongDescription}" >
                <Button.Content>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding ShortDescription}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        <Label Grid.Row="2" Foreground="Red" FontSize="10" Content="{Binding IcdCode}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!--DifferentialTabViewModel-->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DifferentialDiagnosisTabViewModel}">

            <Grid Grid.Row="0" ShowGridLines="False">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border Style="{StaticResource QuestionSectionStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{lang:TranslateLocal DifferentialDiagnoses, DefaultValue=Differential Diagnoses}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock  Grid.Column="2" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{lang:TranslateLocal Note, DefaultValue=Note:}"></TextBlock>

                        <TextBox  Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MaxHeight="100" FontSize="12" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextAlignment="Left"
                                TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" Margin="5,0"
                                Text="{Binding Note.Comment}"/>

                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                    <ui:TextBoxPlus x:Name="txtSearch"
                                    Text="{Binding Path=SearchText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    ClearButtonVisibility="Visible" 
                                    BackgroundText="{lang:TranslateLocal Search, DefaultValue=Search}" 
                                    Margin="4,0,5,0"
                                    Height="{DynamicResource TouchableMinHeight}" Width="300"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Loaded="txtSearch_Loaded" />

                    <Button x:Name="SearchButton" Content="{lang:TranslateLocal Search1, DefaultValue=Search}" IsDefault="True"  
                            Click="SearchButton_Click" Loaded="SearchButton_Loaded"
                            Width="100"
                            Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"
                            CommandParameter=""/>

                    <Button x:Name="AddButton" Content="{lang:TranslateLocal Add, DefaultValue=Add}"
                            Click="AddButton_Click" Loaded="AddButton_Loaded" 
                            Width="100"
                            Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
                            CommandParameter=""/>

                    <Button x:Name="CommonButton" Content="{lang:TranslateLocal Common, DefaultValue=Common}"
                            Click="CommonButton_Click" Loaded="CommonButton_Loaded" 
                            Width="100"
                            Command="{Binding CommonCommand}"
                            CommandParameter=""/>
                    <Button x:Name="InfoButton" Content="{lang:TranslateLocal InfoButton,DefaultValue=InfoButton}"
                            Click="InfoButton_Click" />

                </StackPanel>

                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="DiagnosesList" 
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AvailableDiagnosisDataModel}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Diagnoses}" 
                                  BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                  Background="Transparent"/>
                </ScrollViewer>

                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="SelectedDiagnosesList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SelectedDiagnosisDataModel}"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedDiagnoses}" 
                                     Margin="0"
                                     BorderBrush="Transparent" 
                                     Background="Transparent">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>

            </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

This is legacy/brownfield code. I feel like I'm pretty solid with Wpf Windows but haven't figured out `DataTemplate`s or `Style`s yet

so it seems I was missing an important part of how this guy works to figure out how to refactor or clean it, the code behind after the initialization:

```
    private void DifferentialDiagnosisTab_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm = new DifferentialDiagnosisTabViewModel();
        this.Content = vm;
    }
```

Comment: The usercontrol only has resources, no content.

Comment: does that mean I can't have any of it in the designer? or I should be looking in another file for the actual results?

Comment: @JohanLarsson added details that may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of it shows up in the designer, because [as Johan Larsson noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610142/how-do-i-get-more-any-of-this-to-render-in-the-designer/32610283#comment53071141_32610142), there's nothing to show. All you've done, is define a set of *resources* that the control might use - `Style` and `DataTemplate` resources, namely.

Take the entire `<Grid>` tag (remove its now-empty parent `<DataTemplate>`) and move it out of the `<UserControl.Resources>` tag (before the `</UserControl>` closing tag). Not sure that will give you exactly what you wanted (I only merely glanced at the markup), but you'll have that "ah-HA" moment ;-)

---

In a typical *Model-View-ViewModel* setup, the ViewModel isn't the *content* (your code is setting the control's `Content` at run-time, that's why nothing shows up at design-time), it's the `DataContext`, and the XAML uses bindings to properties of the ViewModel.

You shouldn't need to have that bit of code-behind.

Comment: there's nothing to show at design time, but at runtime this page works. the last datatemplate must be getting applied to the content of the UC. The code-behind sets that to a type that the data template would pick up.

Comment: That bit of C# code that's setting the `Content`, is your answer: the control starts off without any *content* - the designer has nothing to show. BTW that code is completely non-idiomatic. The ViewModel isn't the *content* - it should be assigned to the View's `DataContext`, not `Content`.

Comment: ok, good information, I think I see a way to fix it, trying it now. moving the datatemplate that should be the xaml inside the UC into the UC and setting `DataContext` instead